Find keywords in a list that related with specified topic
Given list of keywords:
gyat
fee
skibidi
expenditure
payment
yapping

How to retrieve keywords that related with a topic, let's say money.
I expect, it returned [1,3,4] which represent indices of keyword that related with its topic.
I'm thinking to use embedding layers of an LLM, and compare with embedding vector representation of money with Cosine Similarity.


Source: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1zUHUF8XFdclxMv0B61UGTwCcA60i-u5H#scrollTo=6b8ihpvKCpcE
Basically, that's exactly what I thougt, it perfect well. Except it also returned negative similarity that can be said as antonym of the word.
